# How to test a function for side-effects using Jest and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, jestjs, side-effects

I'm using Jest for testing.
I want to test if `myFunction( myArray )` has no side-effects:

```
test("that there are no side-effects" ...)
```

How do I write a Jest test that `myArray` doesn't get changed by `myFunction`?

EDIT:

I'm expecting an answer in the form of a Jest test script, and I want to use that side-effect test algorithm for any function and any variable, not just `myFunction( myArray )`.

FILE: myFunction.js

```
export default myFunction;
function myFunction( array ) {
  //any code goes here
  //maybe it changes array
  //maybe it doesn't
  //maybe it returns a value
  //maybe it doesn't
}
```

FILE: myFunction.test.js

```
import myFunction from "myFunction.js";
test("that there are no side-effects", 
  //the Jest test code goes here
  //where I pass myArray into myFunction
  myFunction( myArray )
  //myArray should not be changed by myFunction
  //what should the test code be?
);
```

Comment: Take a copy, and assert that they're still equal afterwards?

Comment: Can you explain what side effects you want to avoid and show the source code?

Comment: Kindly provide more details, if your function is impure, provide full class, or object , private variables.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode), you can [freeze](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) the array before testing the function, and any direct mutation will throw an exception:

> Note that the elements of the array in the code below are primitives, but that preventing mutations of nested objects (including arrays), will require that those objects are also frozen.

```html
<script type="module">

function test (name, fn) {
  try {
    fn();
    console.log('✅', name);
  }
  catch (ex) {
    console.log('❌', name);
    console.log(String(ex));
  }
}

function doubleArrayValues (array) {
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i += 1) {
    array[i] *= 2;
  }
}

function myFunctionPure (array) {
  const copy = [...array];
  doubleArrayValues(copy);
  return copy;
}

function myFunctionImpure (array) {
  doubleArrayValues(array);
  return array;
}

test('myFunctionPure: has no side-effects', () => {
  const myArray = Object.freeze([1, 2, 3]);
  myFunctionPure(myArray);
});

test('myFunctionImpure: has no side-effects', () => {
  const myArray = Object.freeze([1, 2, 3]);
  myFunctionImpure(myArray);
});

</script>
```

Comment: You might also want to use Node's `--use_strict` flag to run Jest.

Comment: @NickMcCurdy Rolling back your edit: the code snippet is designed to run as a module. When not in strict mode, not all mutations to frozen objects throw exceptions.

Comment: I would use `"use strict"` personally, but sorry for any confusion with the edit.

Answer (score 0):

I like the thorough answer from @jsejcksn.
Here's a quick answer:

```
import myFunction from "myFunction.js";

test("that there are no side-effects", () => {
  const myArray = [1,2,3];
  const myArrayCopy = [...myArray];
  const result = myFunction( myArray );
  
  //If the function returns an array,
  //it should not be the same reference
  expect( result ).not.toBe( myArray );
  
  //The original array values should remain the same
  expect( myArray ).toEqual( myArrayCopy );
});
```